# JLabel word wrapping of string with no spaces

Tags: java, swing, word-wrap, jtextarea, jtextcomponent

I am using html to make text in a JLabel span multiple lines. However if I enter a long string with no spaces it doesn't go onto a new line and instead causes an underlying JScrollpane to display a horizontal scrollbar and pushs the components to the right of the JLabel out of the view area. So anyone know if it is possible to word wrap strings without spaces in a JLabel?

Comment: What is the content of this 'long string with no spaces', DNA coding strings?

Comment: It matters to make me care enough to think about the question or offer an answer.  Never mind.

Comment: Dont worry Einstein a guy has already given me an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `JTextArea`for that purpose:

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
ta.setEditable(false);
ta.setLineWrap(true);
ta.setOpaque(false);
ta.setWrapStyleWord(false); // This makes wrapping on char boundaries, and I think is the default value
```